# Can I store WGS84 latitude / longitude directly as spatial data in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, spatial-index, wgs84

I have a set of [WGS84 coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System). The conservative approach is to store them as number ( [What datatype to use when storing latitude and longitude data in SQL databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196415/what-datatype-to-use-when-storing-latitude-and-longitude-data-in-sql-databases) ) and calculate distances as here ( [latitude/longitude find nearest latitude/longitude - complex sql or complex calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234204/latitude-longitude-find-nearest-latitude-longitude-complex-sql-or-complex-calc)).

A little more advanced approach is to create a user defined function for "in range" ( [MySQL User Defined Function for Latitude Longitude Syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640448/mysql-user-defined-function-for-latitude-longitude-syntax) )

[MySQL latitude and Longitude table setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726031/mysql-latitude-and-longitude-table-setup) uses a [spatial index](http://ftp.nchu.edu.tw/MySQL/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-a-spatial-index.html) . But I do not quite get if it is possible to directly store WGS coordinates, and then query a distance based on the `Point` data type?

Example: Data look like this: `"lat" 40.7142298`, `"lng" -73.9614669`, and this is what I'd like to import. Then query like "select all tupel within 10km of lat / lng".

Comment: I could be totally missing the point of your question, but what is the problem in storing a coordinate like "lat=40.7, lng=-73.9" as a `POINT(40.7 -73.9)`? Or is it that you want to avoid the (string) conversion when importing your data?

Comment: Or I miss a point here - I have never used MySQL spatial. How does the DB know 40.7 is a WGS coordinate and not a coordinate in a normal X/Y system, ie. metrical coordinates vs. polar (latitude and longitude). And how do I make obvious that something like 40.30 does not mean 30 minutes but 0.3.

Comment: Now I understand what I missed :) Yes, to calculate a distance from coordinates, you would have to convert linear distances to polar coordinates. This is [not trivial, but it could work](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html). Regarding your second question, the `POINT()` datatype is decimal, so "40.5" must not mean anything else but "forty and a half".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read the [Manual section on the Spatial Extensions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/spatial-extensions.html)?

To query, define a query region (e.g. rectangle) and then filter by `within`

Comment: But the coordinates still look like in an Cartesian coordinate system. Could you point out an example where I can see how it works with polar coordinates as latitude / longitude.

Comment: Use SRIDs. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/creating-spatial-values.html But I don't think MySQL is the best choice anyway.

Comment: There is no best choice. It depends on various factors. For an open source choice, PostgreSQL might be worth a try, but I havn't used it. PostGIS definitely should have tutorials for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

SQL server 2008 has  Geography data type you can use and to query it back use open query. once  that is done, geo spatial your database and start doing stuff.

Comment: I just noticed your asking for MYSQL, I have no idea what is its equivalent in MYSQL but it should have something similer.