# Haversine in MySQL stored function

Tags: mysql

I am to create a stored function that calculates the distance between two points. However I cannot get it to work. Here is the code I am using at the moment.

```
DROP FUNCTION `haversine`//
CREATE DEFINER=`-----`@`%` FUNCTION `haversine`(givenLat DOUBLE, givenLong DOUBLE) RETURNS double
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 
  DECLARE dist double;
  DECLARE longitude varchar(255);
  DECLARE latitude varchar(255);

  SET longitude = 'Longitude';
  SET latitude = 'Latitude';


  SET dist = (6371 * acos( cos( radians
    (givenLat) ) * cos( radians
    ( latitude ) ) * cos( radians
    ( givenLong ) - radians
    (longitude) ) + sin( radians
    (givenLat) ) * sin( radians
    ( latitude ) ) ));
  RETURN dist;
END
```

The following query returns no results while it should return something.

```
SELECT id FROM location_address WHERE haversine(lat, long) < 30;
```

Because when I do (the same?) query manually it returns results:

```
SELECT id,  (6371 * acos( cos( radians
    (lat) ) * cos( radians
    ( Latitude ) ) * cos( radians
    ( long ) - radians
    (Longitude) ) + sin( radians
    (lat) ) * sin( radians
    ( Latitude ) ) )) AS distance 
FROM table HAVING distance < 30
```

I've of course used the same coordinates to try both queries and I really can't figure out why the function does not produce any results.

I really need a stored function to be able to execute a query.

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640448/mysql-user-defined-function-for-latitude-longitude-syntax

Comment: Why set variables to strings such as `SET longitude = 'Longitude';`? Should all the values be numeric?

Comment: Anything against mysql geospatial functions?

Comment: @RyanVincent I've had problems declaring column names as it would result in a MySQL error being thrown that the column does not exist. This way it somehow doesn't. ( coordinates are stored in DB which need to be compared to given coordinates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't exactly know why it works, but passing the column names directly to the function as given parameters worked instead of declaring them in the function itself.